# Can't generate password reset token in MVC 5 project?

Tags: c#, passwords, asp.net-mvc-5, usermanager

I'm having a weird issue. At the moment I'm trying to make a "forgot password" method, so users can get a reset mail when they forget their password. The strange thing is I can't use various methods in the usermanager, which normally work in all other projects. If I create a new mvc project the various methods works fine, but in my particular project it just shows errors and I'm not able to import or do anything about it?

[image: As you can see the various methods are simply shown as non-existing and I cannot import anything?]

Does anyone know why my project is behaving this way or how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are using Resharper. If so, can happen that the Resharper cache gets out of sync. To fix it, try this:

1. Go to Tools -> Options -> ReSharper -> Options -> General and click Clear Caches. Click Cancel and then in the ReSharper options window click Suspend Now and after that click Resume button.
2. Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm, didn't even have to restart VS. :)